# How do you connect the MySQL in Java with IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

How do you connect the MySQL in Java with IntelliJ Idea?When I did,there was always problem that is "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db".

Comment: maybe add the jar to the classpath

Comment: This indicates that you need additional code added to your project.  You may want to have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html#step3 to understand better.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to MySQL with IntelliJ Idea, oder with the program you're writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add "mysql-connector-java.jar" to your class path.If this jar file not found in your class path ,it will throw java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql